# Shutil not copying files when run without idle

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to do a very simple operation, I am trying to copy a png over to another directory from a choice on an input, with a desktop shortcut that runs the file

The code works perfectly in the shell, copies files no problem. but when I just double click on the file, the window pops up, and I enter the input, It does not do anything. The code straight up stops.
This is my code:

```
import shutil
import time


choice = int(input('''1. or  2. 
'''))

if choice == 1:
    src = 'C:\\directory\\image.png'
    print("chosen 1!")


elif choice == 2:
    src = 'C:\\different directory\\image.png'
    print("chosen 2!")


dst = 'C:\\directory\\destination_image.png'
 
print("Trying to copy...")
shutil.copy2(src, dst)
print("File copied successfully.")
time.sleep(3)
```

It never prints the "trying to copy..." piece of code

Comment: Does it print "chosen 1!" or "chosen 2!"?

Comment: Do you also use absolute paths in your actual code or are they only used here in the sample?

Comment: It does not print the chosen 1 or 2, and they are absolute paths in my actual code

Comment: I don't see how that's possible.  Are you sure you're looking in the correct place for the printed output?  Sometimes IDEs show the output in a separate window...

Comment: Nope window just closes after input

Comment: So it does show the `1. or  2.` input prompt?  And if so, what are you typing at the prompt?

Comment: @JohnGordon It does show the input prompt, and I am just entering the number. I sorta think it has something to do with the variables, as when they update it closes. I might also try putting it in a function

Comment: I got it working using a completely different method by opening and writing the file without using shutil, sorry for wasting your time as I do not see any solution possible for this method.